# Daemon crash in embedded system when I define a large local array then memory set in program. Why the array spanned two stacks in daemon?

Tags: c, crash, embedded-linux, daemon, stack-memory

Would someone be able to provide suggestions for this question? I tried for two weeks and couldn't find a solution to fix it.

The problem is when I add a function in daemon, it will be crash in embedded linux：

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 131072

static int newFuntion(unsigned int addr, unsigned int buflen, unsigned char *buf)
{
    printf("BLOCK_SIZE:%d\n",BLOCK_SIZE);
    UINT8 temp[BLOCK_SIZE]; /* sector buffer */
    printf("temp:%x,sizeof UINT8:%d,temp_end:%x\n",temp,sizeof(UINT8),&temp[BLOCK_SIZE-1]);
    memset(temp,0,sizeof(temp)); //processA daemon crash in there
    return 0;
}
```

Although I could't use gdb to catch crash infomation, I fould the correlation between daemon crash and variable declaration. The array "temp" spanned two stacks in daemon.

This is memory allocation in this daemon:

```
~ # cat /proc/pid/maps
00400000-0047c000 r-xp 00000000 1f:07 1083       /bin/processA
0048b000-00494000 rw-p 0007b000 1f:07 1083       /bin/processA
00494000-004ac000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
005b2000-005d3000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
58800000-58a00000 rw-s 00000000 00:01 196614     /SYSV000004d2 (deleted)
775b0000-775c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
775c0000-775c1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
775c1000-776c0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          *[stack:582]*
776c0000-776c1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
776c1000-776e0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          *[stack:578]*
776e0000-777b6000 r-xp 00000000 1f:07 430        /lib/libm-2.20.so
777b6000-777c5000 ---p 000d6000 1f:07 430        /lib/libm-2.20.so
777c5000-777c6000 r--p 000d5000 1f:07 430        /lib/libm-2.20.so
777c6000-777c7000 rw-p 000d6000 1f:07 430        /lib/libm-2.20.so
.
.
.
77dec000-77e0d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
77e0e000-77e2f000 r-xp 00000000 1f:07 473        /lib/ld-2.20.so
77e39000-77e3e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
77e3e000-77e3f000 r--p 00020000 1f:07 473        /lib/ld-2.20.so
77e3f000-77e40000 rw-p 00021000 1f:07 473        /lib/ld-2.20.so
77e40000-77e41000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fa37000-7fa58000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
7fff7000-7fff8000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
```

The array declaration "temp" start from [stack:582] to [stack:578]:

```
BLOCK_SIZE:131072
temp:776bcdb0,sizeof UINT8:1,temp_end:776dcdb0
```

I'm not sure why the array spanned two stacks in daemon.Is this lead to daemon crash?
Have any solution that I still define a large local array but avoid daemon crash?

-------Final Solution------

Thanks hesham_EE so much for valuable suggestion.
I use pthread_attr_setstacksize to set thread stack.
When I change thread stack size from 128KB to 1MB then the daemon still alive when array define and memory set.

Comment: I would start from `printf("temp:%p,sizeof UINT8:%zu,temp_end:%p\n",(void *)temp,sizeof(UINT8),(void *)&temp[BLOCK_SIZE-1]);`

Comment: What about other sizes, what is the stack size?

Comment: Why do you want a large stack-allocated array? Why do not simply allocate the memory using malloc?

Comment: The stack size is 8196 in Linux. I tried to kill the daemon and stack size to "unlimited", then I restart daemon. But It still crashed again when array set memory.

Comment: Is your code multi-threaded?

Comment: `ulimit` shows the stack size in KiB not in bytes.

Comment: @hesham_EE the stack size is 8192(kb).

Comment: @0___________ Could you give me other advice about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main stack, which starts at 0x7fa37000 is not used in the thread that did the printing.

There are two threads that used their own stack, these are the ones labelled [stack:582] and [stack:578]. The numbers here, 582 and 578, are the thread IDs.

From the stack address dump you printed:

> temp:776bcdb0,sizeof UINT8:1,temp_end:776dcdb0

Because stack grows upwards, from the max value of [stack:578] at 776e0000 and the end address of your buffer 776dcdb0, this means the prints are coming from this thread, i.e. [stack:578].

This huge buffer that you have, crosses the 2nd stack to the 1st stack passing by the region in the middle:

> 776c0000-776c1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0

which you don't have read/write access to. This is the reason of the crash.

You either need to check the code and increase the thread stack size to be enough for that buffer. OR, use a buffer with max size around `776e0000-776c1000` which is roughly `120 KB` to keep some overhead of already used stack. More than that, it'll crash.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I try to increase the thread stack size from 128KB to 1MB then the daemon still alive when array define and memory set.

Comment: Great, glad it helped your issue.